# Javascript ES6 import without a name

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, ecmascript-6, vue.js

I am running Webpack, Babel and Vue.js and I want to split up my entry file. Currently I have an app.js file which is the starting point to my application.

I have some bits and pieces of Code I want to put into a `bootstrap.js` file which I want to include in my main `app.js` file can I can have a clean file to start out with Vue and add components in it as I go.

Some examples of what I would want to put in my `bootstrap.js` file:

```
import messagesNL from './translations/nl';

Vue.use(VeeValidate, {
  locale: 'nl',
  dictionary: {
    nl: {
      messages: messagesNL
    }
  }
});

window.Vue = Vue;
```

So pretty much setup for plugins, global configuration, etc. I feel like this is not your typical module and I find it hard to create a module like structure for this file so I basically use this in my `app.js` file:

```
import bootstrap from './bootstrap';
```

Having no idea if this would work, it seems to just import everything neatly without me having done a `module exports {}` like syntax.

Now the bootstrap variable that I assigned to that file is unused in `app.js` since it's only used to require the file and my IDE kind of 'greys` it out to let me know it is unused.

Is there another syntax for this so that I don't have to assign a name to it? Is this approach ok to split up my file, or should I be doing something else?

I haven't put it into a proper module yet because then it would have it's own local scope and I would be unsure how to set up Vue with all the plugins, etc. If anybody has a better suggestion I am open to it.

Cheers.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

To include a file without importing anything you can just drop the `<name> from` part of the statement:

```
import './bootstrap';
```

This will execute the target module without affecting the scope of the active module, but it may have side-effects such as declaring globals or modifying existing globals.

---

As stated in the MDN docs for [Import a module for its side effects only](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import#Import_a_module_for_its_side_effects_only):

> Import an entire module for side effects only, without importing anything. This runs the module's global code, but doesn't actually import any values.
>
> ```
> import '/modules/my-module.js';
> ```

Comment: Is this equivalent to `require('bootstrap');`?

Comment: @Anonymous Yes, it is equivalent to a standalone require statement (one where the result of the call to require is not assigned to anything). However the path in your example is incorrect according to the question. It should be `require('./bootstrap')`.

Comment: The correct way to say this is that you are importing this module *only* for its side-effects. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import#Import_a_module_for_its_side_effects_only

Comment: What is meant by "side-effects only"?  If you import Bootstrap or jQuery, something like, `import '../../assets/jQuery/jquery-3.6.0.js`, is that not available globally?